# Printing Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

My following code print just  only first element. In `print_list()` function, it stops after printing first element. It says after first element, `head->next` is `0`. Shouldn't point towards second element?

I want to simply print whole list.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;    
struct node {
  int x;
  node *next;
};    
node* add_element(node*);
bool is_empty(node*);
void print_list(node*);
node* search(node*);

int main()
{
    node *head;
    head=NULL;
    node* current=head;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i=i+1)
    {
       if (current==NULL)
       { 
         current=add_element(current);
         head=current;
       }
       else{ 
          current=add_element(current);
       }
     }
     cout<<head->next<<endl;

     // DOUBT: head->next gives NULL value. It should give me pointer to 2nd node
     print_list(head);
}     
node* add_element(node* current)
{   
    node* temp;
    temp=new node;
    temp->next=NULL;
    cout<<"enter element"<<endl;
    cin>>temp->x;
    current=temp;
    return current; 
}      
bool is_empty(node* temp)
{
    return temp==NULL;      
}    
void print_list(node* temp)
{
    if (is_empty(temp)==false)
    {   
         cout<<"here temp(head)"<<temp->next<<endl;
         while(temp!=NULL)
         {
            cout<<temp->x<<endl;
            temp = temp->next;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you don't call: `print_list()`

Comment: now added. Thanks for pointing out. But problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print function print first element because you have just one node in the Linked List! Actually the mistake is present in `add_element(node*)`  function, you overwrite address of `head` node with new node (so having memory leak) as I marked below:

```
  node* add_element(node* current)
  {   
    node* temp;         
    temp = new node;     <---" You allocated memory"
    temp->next = NULL;   <---" Set next NULL"
    cout<< "enter element" << endl;
    cin>> temp->x;       <---" Assign a value in new node"    

    // Replace below two line with suggested   
    current = temp;      <---"MISTAKE: Overwrite first node"    
                            "temp next is NULL so losing address of other nodes"

    return current;      <--- "return first node"
  }
```

Next of new node (so first node) is NULL hence the print function prints only first node's value.

**Suggestion:**

You should Correct as follows to add new node as a first node in linked list:

```
temp -> next = current;  // new nodes next if present first node
return temp;             // new code becomes first node
```

Be careful `current` should be NULL initially.

With my suggestion in `add_element()` function also change the for loop code in `main()` as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i < 5; i = i + 1){
    current = add_element(current);
}
head = current;
```

And check the working code at [Codepade](http://codepad.org/L2poK8dq) (instead of user input I added value using `y = 100` variable).

**Edit** To append new node:

You need to check whether new node is first node of not (read comments).

```
  // returns first node address in linked list = head 
  node* add_element(node* head){
    node *temp, *new_nd;

    // Create new node
    new_nd = new node;
    new_nd->next = NULL;
    cout<<"enter element"<<endl;
    cin>>new_nd->x;

    // Is new node is the first node?
    if(!head)  
      return new_nd;

    // move to last 
    temp = head; 
    while(temp->next) temp = temp->next;

    // add new node at last 
    temp->next = new_nd;

    // return old head
    return head;  
  }
```

Also simply main() as below:

```
int main(){
    node *head = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1){
        head = add_element(head);
    }
    print_list(head);
}
```

check this [working code](http://codepad.org/4mHIG9EA).

Comment: when I do current->next=temp, the program stops working. I am using MinGW in Windows7 CMD. –

Comment: @user2419974 You are doing wrong read answer I posted, initially `current` is null you you can't do `current->next=temp`

Comment: I want to append element at the end

Comment: @Nikhil first simply add first Check updated answer. For append you I have to updated answer again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply.

Comment: @Nikhil you can vote all as you gets 15 RPs but accept any one only.

Comment: return current ?? current is not modified.

Comment: @Nikhil **Yes** you always need to return first node. If you add new_nd node as first node return that else return old head that is current. Read updated answer with **linked code**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
node* add_element(node* current)
  {   
    node* temp;   //You created a new node
    temp=new node;  //You allocated it here
    temp->next=NULL;  //You set its next property to null
    cout<<"enter element"<<endl;  //
    cin>>temp->x;
    current=temp;   //This should be current->next = temp. You are overwriting it!
    return current; //And now you are returning essentially the temp object that
                    //You created and you set its next property to NULL
  }
```

You are assigning the node you created in `temp = new node` to the current node that was passed in. What you want to do is assign the node you just created to the current node's next property. It should be `current->next = temp`

Comment: when I do current->next=temp, the program stops working. I am using MinGW in Windows7 CMD.

Comment: Delete head = NULL in your main()

Answer (score 0):

head->next is NULL because you set it so in add_element(). To have a linked list, you should set current->next = temp.

As you're using C++, you might consider using std::list instead of implementing your own linked list.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (current==NULL)
                    { current=add_element(current);
                      head=current;
                    }
                    else
                    { current->next=add_element(current);
                      current=current->next;
                    }
```

> The correct code.
>   You have to make a small correction in the loop.
>   You have to add a new node and then make it point to the next of the current node.
>   so the simplified code is current->next=add_element(current)
>   and then make current point to the new current.